# Move Java installation to a new volume?

Tags: unix, centos, java

How can I move a Java installation to a new volume on my server?

Right now we have Java and the OS (CentOS) running off of a HDD. We're trying to speed things up so would like to have the OS use the SSD drive for Java since the read/write speed is 100x faster.

Does anyone know how we can copy or reinstall java to a new volume?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: How did you installed Java?

Comment: Hi @Braiam, we used Yum

Answer (score 2):

If you used Yum, the thing is not easy, since Java don't install all its files in one place, but different directories like `/var`, `/lib` and `/usr`. I would recommend building Java from sources and configure a prefix for the installation.

When you download the sources, you can set the prefix using `./configure --prefix=/path/to/volume`.

**BUT**, I think the most easy solution is clone the operative system and use the entire SSD as the main disk, then configure the `fstab` to mount no critical directories there, like `/tmp` or `/var/cache`, etc. in the old disk.